# Missing make_comb_mat function in R UpSet plot library

Tags: r

I'm following the example on this site to format the data for the Upset plot:

https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/upset-plot.html

```
library(UpSetR)
set.seed(123)
lt = list(a = sample(letters, 5),
          b = sample(letters, 10),
          c = sample(letters, 15))
m1 = make_comb_mat(lt)
m1
```

The code fails at this line:

```
m1 = make_comb_mat(lt)
```

With the following error:

```
Error in make_comb_mat(lt) : 
  no se pudo encontrar la función "make_comb_mat"
```

(can't not find function "make_comb_mat")

Answer (score 2):

The make_comb_mat() function is from the ComplexHeatmap package, which has implemented its own version of the upset function.

The ComplexHeatmap package is available on github: https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap